# PHP Soap - Can't import schema

Tags: php, web-services, soap, nginx

I want to connect to a Soap server, but I have the error :

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from 'http://domain.com:80/services.xsd
```

I took a look on other questions, and I have my "allow_url_open" to ON, I use SOAP_1_1 and OpenSSL is enabled.
Something is weird, the URL to my SOAP server is :

```
https://domain.com/services?WSDL
```

And in the error, there is no more "https", but only "http" on port 80. I tried :

```
wget https://domain.com/services?WSDL
```

And it works. I have an XML file with all my services. But, using PHP and :

```
try
{
    $client = new SoapClient('https://domain.com/services?wsdl',         
    array(
        "trace" => 1,
         "soap_version" => SOAP_1_1
   ));                 
}
catch (SoapFault $e)
{
   var_dump($e);
}
```

I have the "Parsing Schema: can't import schema" error. Do I need to configure something else on my PHP ? I am using Nginx and PHP-FPM 5. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
http://domain.com:80/services.xsd
```

Are you able to access above link in your browser?

No, I guess.Similarly it is not accessible through your code also.
This schema location must be defined in your wsdl i.e.

```
 https://domain.com/services?WSDL
```

You can add those elements from schema into wsdl.
You can follow this approach to get rid of it.

```
http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2007/05/improving-wcf-interoperability-flattening-your-wsdl.html
```

Comment: I can't access this link, I suppose there is an error in the WSDL, the schemaLocation is not the good one. I tried to access : "https://domain.com/services.xsd", and it works. You're right, schemaLocation is defined in my WSDL. I have wrote to my SOAP provider, waiting for him...

Comment: But if you are able to access this xsd from browser then there should be no issue, while your wsdl is trying to access it.I am little confused. keep searching about Nginx and PHP-FPM 5 settings. May be we are missing some configuration.

Comment: In fact, I can access "https ://domain.com/services.xsd", but not "http ://domain.com:80/services.xsd". I guess it's the problem.

Comment: Actually port 80 is usually blocked by www publish services like Apache or other web applications. If you can identify and stop listening or using port 80 in your system. You can solve this problem.Just a hunch.

Comment: But all sites I can access are on port 80 ? I can't "wget domain.com:80", but it works for "www.google.fr", which is on port 80 I suppose ? I just think there is an error in the WSDL.