# PHP SOAP Error Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from

Tags: php, xml, soap, xsd, wsdl

I am trying to create a SOAP Client from a WSDL file, but I always get this error bellow.
`Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from 'https://..../CreateQuote?xsd=createQuote_datamodel.xsd', namespace must not match the enclosing schema 'targetNamespace' in C:\xampp\htdocs\kfz\test.php:23 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\kfz\test.php(23): SoapClient->SoapClient('https://testws1...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\kfz\test.php on line 23`

Here is my code:

```
$xml = file_get_contents("out.xml");

$soapOptions = array(
   'soap_version'    => SOAP_1_1,
   'exceptions'      => true,
   'trace'           => 1,
   'wsdl_local_copy' => false,
   'keep_alive'      => true,
);
$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, $soapOptions);
$soapClient->CreateQuote($xml);
```

Can anyone help me please?
I also tried it with non WSDL mode but it's still not working

Comment: Maybe  check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21432847/6028607

Comment: Can you post your actual code so we can help you?

Comment: I can access the wsdl and xsd files from browser and also with wget